# Transform property in Firefox and Dropdown bug

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am having an issue with a form in a popup container that is using the css property transform:translate to center the popup.

I have a a form inside with select fields and the dropdowns are not moving with the rest of the content. They are positioned where the popup would be if it didn't have the transform property on it.

This is only happening in Firefox. I've tried adding transform:none to the select fields and child elements, as well as using a transform that is the opposite of the popup but nothing is working. Does anyone know a fix for this? Thank you.

Comment: hmm, are you using `select` replacement plugins ? (*to style the select elements*)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an animation styling property on the popup. I removed it and boom, back to normal. Thanks, Gaby aka G. Petrioli, for the reply.

```
.smile-3DRotateBottom {
-webkit-animation-name: smile-3DRotateBottom;
animation-name: smile-3DRotateBottom;
-webkit-perspective: 1300px;
perspective: 1300px;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
transform-origin: 0 100%;
```

}